# Is there a reason to write an IIFE invoked with a leading 'not'-operator (!) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iife

there are two (common) ways to implement an IIFE in Javascript.

```
// Way 1
(function(){
/* My IIFE Body*/
})()

//Way 2 
!function(){
/* My IIFE Body*/
}()
```

I want to know if there is a good reason that one would use the second one. 
 I only see reasons to **not** use the second one. For example if you want your IIFE to return something you cannot assign it to a variable like this:

```
var x = 
(function()
{ return 5; })(); // x will be 5

var y = 
!function()
{ return 5; }(); // y will be true
```

since it will be cast to boolean. Whenever I want to access an object from a Way-2-IIFE I use a closure like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2bcn4hv/1/).
There is also no performance boost for the second variant as you can see [here](http://jsperf.com/js-iife-test). 

 So are there any good reasons to use method two? If so, can you give me an example ?

Comment: I think you mean "leading" instead of "trailing".

Answer (score 1):

People use the second approach because it saves one byte (`!` vs. `(` and `)`).

Comment: Two seconds after the question was closed :-)